# Branch vs Trunk

Tags: svn, version-control, merge

We have a project that we have been coding in the trunk. The trunk now has a large feature which has been coded but we do not wish to ship in the first version.

But we also want to cleanup code for the first release and hence wish to remove all the files and functions caused by this feature from the project for version 1.

However, we will need all the files and functions back once we are ready to ship version 2.

In order to do this in the most efficient way, should we keep the feature in the trunk and create a separate branch for version 1 release. In this case we will remove all files and functions related to the feature from the branch and then after release will merge this branch back to the trunk.

Or should we keep the feature related files and functions in a separate branch and then cleanup the trunk. After release we may merge the branch back into the trunk to get the feature.

Which of the two is a better approach?
a) Branch for the feature and trunk for the cleaned up release
b) Trunk for the feature and branch for the cleaned up release

Say I follow the following steps.

1. I create a branch Branch-V1. At this instance, both the trunk and
   the Branch-V1 have the BigFeature.
2. I delete and modify files in Branch-V1 to eliminate the BigFeature completely.
3. I ship V1 from Branch-V1
4. I tag Branch-V1.
5. I merge Branch-V1 into trunk.

Would I not loose the BigFeature in the trunk when I merge the Branch-V1 with the trunk?

Answer (score 1):

better approach is to branch from the trunk just before the big feature was started, then apply your changes to this version 1 branch and when you're ready merge the v1 onto the trunk to create a v2 trunk.

Sounds complicated but its the least effort to fix your problem - so work on a dedicated v1 branch, release that, and then merge back onto trunk ready for v2.

The moment you do that though, first thing you must do is make a new tag of your release 1 code just before merging your changes onto trunk. Then you must start working properly once you have the v2 code on the trunk, branch from trunk to a new 'big feature' branch and finish it off, and make a branch for any other features you want to add. Merge them ontp the trunk when they are complete, and when you release make a 'tag' branch form trunk.

You could clean your repository up by dumping it all, renaming the 2 branches so the v2 trunk culd be renamed to 'v2 branch' and the branch of v1's code could become the trunk. If you're confident to do this, I'd recommend it as it would fix things and you could pretend you'd been working in a properly organised way all along :)

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do this is as follows:-

1. Create branch "v-1.0" from trunk at the revision where you started making changes for this big feature. If it is difficult for you to track the revision number down, just make the branch from the current revision and undo the changes you have been making as you yourself suggested in #2.

> svn copy -r rev-num /trunk /branches/v-1.0

2. Go ahead with "v-1.0" and ship the product from this branch when done.
   For every commit that goes in 1.0, I would be sure to commit it in trunk as well (resolving any conflicts then and there). Generally in big projects, the development in trunk is also going on in parallel.
3. After 1.0 is out of the door, create a tag for the release say "v-1.0" and if there is any additional requests on this release or patches are to be delivered, you can use this same branch.

> svn copy /branches/v1.0 /tags/v-1.0

Thus, you can continue development in branch as well as in trunk.

Comment: My only doubt is when I undo the changes in the branch and then also in the trunk would not all the cleanup happen in the trunk as well?

Comment: Well, you should not undo the changes in trunk because you are going to need them for the future release. Make the changes only in the branch - that is the whole point of creating a branch.